# Error in Implementing Quantum SVM

Tags: qiskit, programming, machine-learning

I am getting Type error of invalid parameter in base sampler module. From what I know sampler is constructor and doesn't take any parameter values, on the qisit.org tutorial of svm they have even said it gets constructed by default.
here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZZFeatureMap
from qiskit_machine_learning.kernels import FidelityQuantumKernel
from qiskit.algorithms.state_fidelities import ComputeUncompute
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler
from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms import QSVC

data=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
X = data.loc[1:1000,["marital","balance","loan"]].values
Y = data.iloc[:1000,-1].values
for i in range(0,1000):
    if Y[i]=='yes':
       Y[i]='1'
    else:
        Y[i]='0'

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)
data_feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=3, reps=2,entanglement='linear' )
sampler = Sampler()
fidelity = ComputeUncompute(sampler=sampler)
data_kernel = FidelityQuantumKernel(feature_map=data_feature_map,fidelity=fidelity)
qsvc = QSVC(quantum_kernel=data_kernel)
qsvc.fit(x_train, y_train)
qsvc_score = QSVC.score(x_test, y_test)



print(f"Callable kernel classification test score: {qsvc_score}")
```

and here is my error :

```
      File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\qsvm.py", line 30, in <module>
    qsvc.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 251, in fit
    fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 314, in _dense_fit
    X = self._compute_kernel(X)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 512, in _compute_kernel
    kernel = self.kernel(X, self.__Xfit)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\qiskit_machine_learning\kernels\fidelity_quantum_kernel.py", line 121, in evaluate
    kernel_matrix = self._get_symmetric_kernel_matrix(
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\qiskit_machine_learning\kernels\fidelity_quantum_kernel.py", line 212, in _get_symmetric_kernel_matrix       
    kernel_entries = self._get_kernel_entries(left_parameters, right_parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\qiskit_machine_learning\kernels\fidelity_quantum_kernel.py", line 234, in _get_kernel_entries
    kernel_entries = np.real(job.result().fidelities)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\qiskit\primitives\primitive_job.py", line 50, in result
    return self._future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\qiskit\algorithms\state_fidelities\compute_uncompute.py", line 141, in _run
    job = self._sampler.run(circuits=circuits, parameter_values=values, **opts.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\qiskit\primitives\base\base_sampler.py", line 172, in run
    parameter_values = self._validate_parameter_values(
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\SEM Project\venv\lib\site-packages\qiskit\primitives\base\base_primitive.py", line 108, in _validate_parameter_values
    raise TypeError("Invalid parameter values, expected Sequence[Sequence[float]].")
TypeError: Invalid parameter values, expected Sequence[Sequence[float]].
```

Comment: What qiskit modules are you using and what are versions? You can get with `from qiskit import __qiskit_version__`, please add them to your question :)

Comment: I'd double check that you have numpy array as `x_train` and `y_train` and the data inside them are only numerical. Looks like you have some non-numerical data.

Comment: @Anton Dekusar yeah that was the case. Thanks for helping out